# Can TDD Handle Complex Projects without an upfront design?

Tags: tdd, uml

The idea of TDD is great, but i'm trying to wrap my head around how to implement a complex system if a  design is not proposed upfront.

For example, let's say I have multiple services for an payment processing application. I'm not sure I understand how development would/can proceed across multiple developers if there is not a somewhat solid design upfront.

It would be great if someone can provide an example and high level steps to putting together a system in this manner. I can see how TDD can lead to simpler and more robust code, I'm just not sure how it can bring together 1) different developers to a common architectural vision and 2) result in a system that can abstract out behavior in order to prevent having to refactor large chunks of code (e.g. accept different payment methods or pricing models based on a long term development roadmap).

I see the refactoring as a huge overhead in a production system where data model changes increase risks for customers and the company.

Clearly i'm probably missing something that TDD gurus have discovered....

Comment: Concerning your first question, the TDD book "Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided By Tests" clearly states that even with TDD, the system's overall architecture must be decided upon at the beginning. This book includes a "worked example" which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for the book. I read this over the past month and it was helpful to view it in this context. I wish it was in Ruby, but the Java examples and detailed framework were nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't claim to be a TDD guru, but here are some thoughts based on the information in your question.

My thoughts on #1 above: As you have mentioned, you need to have an architectural design up-front - I can't think of a methodology that can be successful without this. The architecture provides your team with the cohesion and vision. You may want to do just-enough-design up front, but that depends on how agile you want to be. The team of developers needs to know how they are going to put together the various components of the system before they start coding, otherwise it will just be one big hackfest.

> It would be great if someone can provide an example and high level
>   steps to putting together a system in this manner

If you are putting together a system that is composed of services, then I would start by defining the service interfaces and any messages that they will exchange. This defines how the various components of your system will interact (this would be an example of your up-front design). Once you have this, you can allocate various development resources to build the services in parallel.

As for #2; one of the advantages of TDD is that it presents you with a "safety net" during refactoring. Since your code is covered with unit tests, when you come to change some code, you will know pretty soon if you have broken something, especially if you are running continuous integration (which most people do with a TDD approach). In this case you either need to adapt your unit tests to cover the new behavior OR fix your code so that your unit tests pass.

> result in a system that can abstract out behavior in order to prevent
>   having to refactor large chunks of code

This is just down to your design, using e.g. a [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx) to allow you to abstract and replace behavior. TDD does not prescribe that your design has to suffer. It just asks that you only do what is required to satisfy some functional requirement. If the requirement is that the system must be able to adapt to new payment methods or pricing models, then that is then a point of your design. TDD, if done correctly, will make sure that you are satisfying your requirements and that your design is on the right lines.

> I see the refactoring as a huge overhead in a production system where
>   data model changes increase risks for customers and the company.

One of the problems of software design is that it is a [wicked problem](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/09/development-is-inherently-wicked.html) which means that refactoring is pretty much inevitable. Yes, refactoring is risky in production systems, but you can mitigate that risk and TDD will help you. You also need to have a supple design and a system with low coupling. TDD will help reduce your coupling since you are designing your code to be testable. And one of the by-products of writing testable code is that you reduce your dependencies on other parts of the system; you tend to code to interfaces which allows you to replace an implementation with a mock or stub. A good example of this is replacing a call to a database with a mock/stub that returns some known data - you don't want to hit a database in your unit tests. I guess I can mention here that a good mocking framework is invaluable with a TDD approach ([Rhino mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) and [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) are both open source).

I am sure there are some real TDD gurus out there who can give you some pearls of wisdom...Personally, I wouldn't consider starting a new project with out a TDD approach.

Comment: Nice overall response to all my points. I'm starting to be a believer that TDD can save some time, but with the "right" amount of footwork done ahead of time as well.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, It depends on the the team's composition and appetite for risk.

- If the team consists of several experienced and good designers, you need a less formal 'architecture' phase. It could be just a back of the napkin doodle or a a couple of hours on the whiteboard followed by furious coding to prove the idea. If the team is distributed and/or contains lots of less skilled designers, you'd need to put more time/effort (thinking and documenting) in the design phase before everyone goes off on their own path
- The next item that I can think of is to be risk first. Continually assess what are the risks to your project, calculate your exposure/impact and have mitigation plans. Focus on risky and difficult to reverse decisions first. If the decision is easily reversible, spend less time on it.

Skilled designers are able to evolve the architecture in tiny steps... if you have them, you can tone down the rigor in an explicit design phase

Comment: +1 Yes, i definitely realized that for us, a bit more architecture upfront was very helpful and significantly cut down on refactorings. We know it's not perfect and we can use TDD to evolve, but a firm design "core" upfront makes it much easier to flex the overall design and development.

Answer (score 1):

TDD can necessitate **some** upfront design but definitely not **big** design upfront. because no matter how perfect you think your design is before you start writing code, most of the time it won't pass the reality check TDD forces on it and will blow up to pieces halfway through your TDD session (or your code will blow up if you absolutely want to bend it to your original plan).

The great force of TDD is precisely that it lets your design emerge and refine as you write tests and refactor. Therefore you should start small and simple, making the least assumptions possible about the details beforehand.

Practically, what you can do is sketch out a couple of UML diagrams with your pair (or the whole team if you really need a consensus on the big picture of what you're going to write) and use these diagrams as a starting point for your tests. But get rid of these models as soon as you've written your first few tests, because they would do more harm than good, misleading you to stick to a vision that is no longer true.